# Set a BindingBase property as Binding in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a `BindingBase` property in the code-behind:

```
public BindingBase MyBinding { get; set; }
```

In the code-behind, I can set the binding on a `DependencyProperty` this way:

```
myTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, MyBinding);
```

Is there any way to define it in XAML?

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyBinding}" />
```

as it tries to create a new binding to the `MyBinding` property.

Comment: It doesn't work because binding should be defined between properties.
In your case between property Text in TextBox and some MyProperty in your view model, whereas you're trying to bind property to the Binding.

Comment: "I have, in the code-behind, a BindingBase property" This is where your trouble begins. Why do you have such a property at all?

Comment: Maybe you want to search for a tutorial about MVVM pattern.

Comment: @Clemens To be able to define the binding when I put my `UserControl` in my `Window` XAML and use this binding in a `DataTemplate` in my `UserControl`. Exactly as in `GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding`.

Comment: With the significant difference that DisplayMemberBinding (and other similar properties) are the target, and not the source of a XAML binding expression.

Comment: @Clemens They are the target when you use it from outside of the UserControl. And inside the control, they are the source. Is it possible to use this as source in XAML or must we use the code-behind?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [GridViewColumn source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/GridViewColumn.cs) to find out how the DisplayMemberBinding property is used internally.

Comment: @Clemens Once again, I know how to use it in code-behind. My question is "how to use it in XAML?"

Answer (score 0):

Your `Source` and `Target` should be of same type, or better use a `Convertor`.

`TextBlock.Text` is string, and you are binding it to a `Binding` type. So, `ToString()` would be called.

And if you want to mimic what you have done in your code-behind, then you have to create a separate class eg `public class CustomBinding : BindingBase` .

And use it like this :

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <local:CustomBinding>
            ...
        </local:CustomBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```